# Bluetooth 5.1 AoA(Angle of Arrival)/AoD(Angle of Departure) function availability in Linux/Android

Tags: android, linux, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

We focus on indoor positioning system development. We recently got two development boards with bluetooth 5.1 chip with Ubuntu 18.04 platform and Android 10 platform respectively. We have searched on the internet and we have not find blueZ and Flouride has information about ble 5.1 AOA/AOD or CTE(Constant Tone Extension), and it is the same for Android api. We appreciate it if any expert knows how to enable CTE function in Ubuntu or Android.
Thank you!
Jeremy

Comment: Regarding BlueZ, I would recommend contacting the [BlueZ mailing list](http://www.bluez.org/development/lists/). All the experts are really gathered there.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not supported yet on neither Linux nor Android. You can find the supported features on Linux and the releases here:-

- [About BlueZ](http://www.bluez.org/about/)
- [BlueZ releases and supported features](http://www.bluez.org/)

And on Android below is a list of supported features

- [Android BLE](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/ble-overview)

Comment: Hi Youssif, got it. Thank you for your help. I would like to mark the answer helpful, but it said I can not vote yet. Thank you!